# How do I transfer a MERN stack project from one computer to another

Tags: javascript, reactjs, git, mern

I need to transfer this MERN stack project from my main PC to my laptop but I'm not sure how to do it.

[image: This is my full stack, all my front-end stuff is in the client folder while back-end is outside]

Comment: why dont you use git?

Comment: @Krishnadev.V I don't know exactly how to, since I'm still new to that stuff, that's why I asked.

Comment: the best way to get transfer is by using git

Comment: See https://dev.to/birdy/mern-stack-project-setup-to-push-to-github-4l5e

Comment: There is no need to use githib for this, just in case. You can push directly into the other computer.... or you can pull from the main computer into the laptop, as long as there is a transport that gives visibility to one of the repos (hhtp, ssh  etc).

Comment: @eftshift0 could you explain more ?

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a computer with a repo with a project. You want to put it in another computer. So.... you go to the other computer with ssh (because the other computer is a linux box that has a ssh service installed and working, right?), and create a repo there.... suppose that it's something like:

```
git init /home/myself/projects/the-project
cd home/myself/projectd/the-project
git branch -m whatever #so that git does not complain when we push the real branch
```

I used a full path there so that we can see how to use it later, but it can be done with relative paths, just in case.

Then  in the box that has the project right now yo do:

```
git remote add the-other-box myself@the-other-box-ip:/home/myself/projects/the-peoject
git push the-other-box main # push the branch of the project
```

Now you gonto the other box

```
git checkout main # and now you see the content of the project
```

And that's it